# Qt Rubberband selection rect transparent

Tags: c++, qt, qt5

How to make rubber band selection transparent? I tried this code, but it doesn't work:

```
void RubberBand::mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent* event) { 
    if (event->buttons() != Qt::LeftButton) return; 
    if (rubberBand.isVisible()) {
        rubberBand.hide(); 
        return; 
     } 
     auto posItem = RelativeClippedCoordinates(event->globalPos()); 
     origin = CoordinatesItemToGlobal(pixmapItem, posItem); 
     selectionRect.setTopLeft(posItem); 
     rubberBand.setGeometry(QRect(origin, QSize())); 
     rubberBand.setStyleSheet("background-color:trasparent;"); 
     rubberBand.show(); 
}
```

Comment: void RubberBand::mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent* event)
{
 if (event->buttons() != Qt::LeftButton) return;
 if (rubberBand.isVisible())
 {
  rubberBand.hide();
  return;
 }

 auto posItem = RelativeClippedCoordinates(event->globalPos());

 origin = CoordinatesItemToGlobal(pixmapItem, posItem);
 selectionRect.setTopLeft(posItem);
    rubberBand.setGeometry(QRect(origin, QSize()));
    rubberBand.setStyleSheet("background-color:trasparent;");
    rubberBand.show();
}

Comment: Above is my code

Comment: @mahesht please take a [2-minute tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) first then learn [how to format](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) your post

Comment: You wrote `color:trasparent` instead of `color:transparent`.

Comment: It is difficult to offer solutions when the problem statement is simply, "it doesn't work".  Please [edit] your question to give a more complete description of what you expected to happen and how that differs from the actual results.  See [ask] for hints on what makes a good explanation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to perform this task we must override the `paintEvent` method and activate the `Qt::WA_TranslucentBackground` attribute.

**customrubberband.h**

```
#ifndef CUSTOMRUBBERBAND_H
#define CUSTOMRUBBERBAND_H

#include <QRubberBand>

class CustomRubberBand : public QRubberBand
{
public:
    CustomRubberBand(Shape s, QWidget * p = 0);

protected:
    void paintEvent(QPaintEvent *);
};

#endif // CUSTOMRUBBERBAND_H
```

**customrubberband.cpp**

```
#include "customrubberband.h"

#include <QPainter>

CustomRubberBand::CustomRubberBand(Shape s, QWidget *p): QRubberBand(s, p)
{
    setAttribute(Qt::WA_TranslucentBackground, true);
}

void CustomRubberBand::paintEvent(QPaintEvent *)
{

    if(isVisible()){
        QPainter painter(this);
        painter.setPen(Qt::blue);
        painter.setBrush(QBrush(QColor(85, 142, 253, 100)));
        painter.drawRect(rect());
    }
}
```

[image]

In your case you must change:

**RubberBand.h**

```
#include <QRubberBand>
[...]
QRubberBand rubberBand;
```

to

```
#include "customrubberband.h"
[...]
CustomRubberBand rubberBand;
```

---

<sub>Complete code: https://github.com/eyllanesc/stackoverflow/tree/master/others/qimvi</sub>

Comment: I tried but it didn't work. Background color is still blue.

Comment: I have added image.  click on "rubberband make transparent"

Comment: https://github.com/stil/qimvi

Comment: check this github link. You will get all code. i wanted to make selection part from the rubberband transparent. Please help me if you have any idea.

Comment: I am using 5.7.1 version

Comment: How can i add grid lines on an image. and i want to move those lines.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44602028/how-to-move-lines-in-graphicview-after-moving-update-co-ordinates

Comment: Hello Can i get one more help from you? The rubberband whatever we are drawing. Its not fixed on QGraphicsview. If i close window then its coming out of the window. Please help me if you know the answer.